# Condition Sentence for Nested multiple Embeddable Link Field

Tags: templating, dwt

I'm trying to implement Condition Sentence for nested multiple embeddable link field in the DW Tempate.

But in the 1st Repeat sentence, I can't judge if the 2nd embeddable link field is empty or not.

could you give me any ideas for this?

Thank you very much in advance.

My code is below

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.Embeddable_Block_Items" -->

<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Field.Embeddable_Image_Link_Items != '' || Field.Description != ''" -->
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Field.Description != ''" -->
This should be worked.
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->

<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat  name="Field.Embeddable_Image_Link_Items" -->
This should worked ${TemplateRepeatIndex}
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Naoki, the forums are closed to a lot of people so please could you add the detail here? It would also increase your chances of getting more answers!

Comment: Hi! Dave. Thank you very much for your advice.
I edit my topic.

Answer (score 4):

How to handle nested repeating regions has been explained by Frank van Puffelen on Stack Overflow before here: [How to handle nested repeating regions in Dreamweaver TBBs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309577/how-to-handle-nested-repeating-regions-in-dreamweaver-tbbs-in-sdl-tridion-2011-s#answer-10322575)

Most of the time the trick is in knowing what variables to use where. There are a couple of crucial variables that can help you here, being: Field, FieldPath and TemplateRepeatIndex. You can simply add the following fragment in your DWT (inside every TemplateBeginRepeat) while you are building/debugging your Template.

```cs
(FieldPath=@@FieldPath@@, TemplateRepeatIndex=@@TemplateRepeatIndex@@)
```

Also note that when nesting repeating regions, there is only one TemplateRepeatIndex, that of the current region you are in. More on that topic can also be found on [Tridion Practice - Iterate over multi-value multi-level embedded fields in DWT](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/IteratingOverMultivalueEmbeddedFields)

Comment: Excellent tip Bart! It would appear however that the poster's problem is not accessing outer loop variables but testing if a multivalue embedded field has any values. I'll agree that the question title is misleading...

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume "Embeddable_Image_Link_Items" is a multivalue embedded field? In that case you cannot directly test if the field has content in a DWT.

Your can either use a "hack" in the DWT to assess if the field has any content by using a template repeat region:
`<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Field.Embeddable_Image_Link_Items" -->

    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex = 0" -->

    Field has value (one or more)

    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->

    <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->`

Or if your multivalue embedded field has mandatory subfields you can use
`<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Field.Embeddable_Image_Link_Items.subfield" -->

    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->`
which will evaluate to true if any of the embedded fields have a value for "subfield".

Or you need to create a C# fragment or assembly TBB to determine if the field has value and push this into a separate package variable which you evaluate in your DWT.
    `<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Embeddable_Image_Link_Items_HasValues" -->

    Field has value (one or more)

    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->`